# How to get rid off the apache error?

Tags: php, apache

I'm using PHP, Smarty, jQuery, etc. for my website. I'm getting following error from the apache error log.

```
[Mon Apr 14 12:27:02 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/smart-rebate-web/web/admin/change_password.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/admin/
```

I've checked all the configuration settings and permissions. Everything is correct. Then why this error is coming from apache? Also there is no error printing in a bowser when I run a webpage, ablank webpage appears. I googled a lot about the solution but couldn't find out the exact solution. Checked all the configurration settings. So, can anyone help me in resolving this error please? If you need any further information I can provide you the same.

Comment: The error isn't coming from Apache - it's coming from PHP (`PHP Fatal error`), and it's because you're including an unexisting file (`change_password.php` using `require` or `require_once`). Fix the path that it's including.

Comment: @h2ooooooo:but I got this error from apache error log file. And I checked the file it is existing there.

Comment: It's also not giving the filename from where the error is coming

Comment: My guess is that it's coming from an extension or through `eval`'d code. Can you confirm? Is it possible to comment out the line?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your php.ini and set

```
display_errors = on
```

and restart your web server, you will get errors on browser ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not the soloution of my problem.

Comment: It seems your file is not existing - can you check the file and path once again? Try file_exists('YOUR_FULL_FILE_PATH')